# Use $_GET together with $_POST

Tags: php

I'm trying to post a new record in a table with `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">`. But every row in my table has an unique id, and that id is put next to every `name`. So I'm trying to get the id with `$_GET` but it's been unsuccesful so far. Is the method I'm trying wrong or am I doing something else wrong? If anybody can tell me what's going wrong, I'd appreciatie.

**PHP that gets placed above `<html>`**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['saveRecord'])) {
        if (isset($_POST["newRecord"]) && !empty($_POST["newRecord"])) {
            $id = $_GET['record'];
            $klant=$_POST['newRecord'].$id;
            $query = "INSERT INTO table2
                (recordid, recordname)
                VALUES
                (NULL, '$record')";

            mysqli_query($con, $query);
        }
    }
?>
```

**Markup**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <?php
            $query = ("select * from table1");
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $id = $row['rowid'];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="newRecord<?php echo $id; ?>" type="text" name="newRecord<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <a href="?record=<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <button class="saveRecord<?php echo $id; ?>" name="saveRecord<?php echo $id; ?>">Save</button>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: If you echo the GET variable at the top of the script what do you get?

Comment: Also what is the value `$_POST['saveRecord']` ?

Comment: GET variables have to exist in the URL - you should be using POST for everything if you're populating it to a form.

Comment: Make input name static name="newRecord<?php echo $id; ?>"

Comment: When I click the submit button, it automaticly inserts the records so I can't see the echo. I've even tried stripping down the code and running it with a set `$id` in php fiddle. But no luck.

Comment: why you want that?? its not a good approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother trying to do both at once (the $_GET variables will only be passed if it is included in the action of the form).

The script won't pick up the the records from the $_POST as the names of the field have the ID included in them.

Either create each record as an individual form (move the whole lot inside the WHILE loop), or you could use the ID held within the field name, like this:

```
$newdata = array();
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
  if ((substr($k,0,9) == 'newRecord') && (!empty($v)) {
    $id = substr($k,9);
    $klant = $v;

    $newdata[$id] = $klant;
  }
}
```

Which should extract the ID from the field name and associate it with the data entered to the form.

Comment: Nice that did the trick. I do have a question about `substr($k,10);`. I'm not very good with php, in this context what does this `subtstr` do?

Comment: I'm having trouble with storing it in an array. Like I explained in my question, every row used to have a form. But now it takes every `newRecord` from each table row. Thus creating an array full of empty arrays except one. Could you perhaps show an example?

Comment: [link](newRecord)[/link]

It takes a subsection of a string, in this case (and I edited it, an incident of miscounting) the first nine characters (which would read 'newrecord') the second use of it takes the rest of the string (starting from the ninth index position in the string, the first character being zero).

I've also edited to not store any blank records and how to store it in an array, you can then perform another foreach loop on that array. You might want to check that there's anything in that $newdata array before doing anything further.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for time, I appreciate these tips and I will definitely use them in the near future :)

Answer (score 1):

Your button name is

```
name="saveRecord<?php echo $id; ?>
```

SO this condition need `$id`

```
  if (isset($_POST['saveRecord'])) {// your id missing
```

Comment: That was something I tried before. I got error because right there the `$id` is unkown since it's on top of the `<html>`. That's why I'm looking for a way to use `$_GET`.

Comment: What do you see with `var_dump($_GET, $_POST)`?
`if (isset($_POST['saveRecord'].$_GET['record'])) {`
..to be exactly more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

move your opening and closing form tags in while loop,it will submit only 1 form at a time,otherwise all the inputs will be submitted.

Comment: It's illigal to place `<form>`'s inside a table. That's why I'm using `id`'s instead.

Comment: cant you use jquery or some ajax techniques?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I came here.